# What's the difference in printing a value contained in an array key and printing a value contained in an array key of object property?

Tags: php, arrays, object, key, type-coercion

Consider below code snippets and their respective outputs :

**Code snippet 1 :**

```
<?php
  $juices = array("apple", "orange", "koolaid1" => "purple");

  echo "He drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
  echo "He drank some $juices[1] juice.".PHP_EOL;

  class people {
    public $john = "John Smith";
  }

  $people = new people();

  echo "$people->john drank some $juices[0] juice.".PHP_EOL;
?>
```

**Output of Code snippet 1 :**

```
He drank some apple juice.
He drank some orange juice.
John Smith drank some apple juice.
```

**Code snippet 2 :**

```
<?php
  class foo {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    function __construct() {
      $this->foo = 'Foo';
      $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
  }

  $foo = new foo();
  $name = 'MyName';

  echo "My name is \"$name\". I am printing some $foo->foo.
  Now, I am printing some $foo->bar[1].";
?>
```

**Output of Code Snippet 2 :**

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in hello.php on line 16
My name is "MyName". I am printing some Foo. Now, I am printing some Array[1].
```

If you look closely you can see that in first program I'm able to print a values contained in keys of an array viz. `$juices[0], $juices[1]` but in the second program I'm getting a Notice when I try to print a value contained in an array key and the array is an object property.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting this **Array to String conversion notice** for second program.

Someone, please clear the differences to me with good explanation and help me in printing the array key value in second program.

Comment: Wrap `$foo->bar[1]` in braces.  `{$foo->bar[1]}`

Comment: Or put the `$foo->bar[1]` outside the string. `echo "Now, I am printing some " . $foo->bar[0];`

Comment: @PatrickQ : I know the solution i.e. enclose the expression into curly braces{}. My question is still unanswered. I'm still not understanding the why the way to access both of these entities is different?

Comment: Because objects are different than arrays.  It's really that simple.  You might as well be asking "Why are array values accessed with [] and not -> ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can correctly determine the intended element and object that you are referencing in the first code block.  However, in the second, PHP wants to be crystal clear on how to access the element of the object.  PHP bends over backward in other cases to make coding simple (type-jugging and other such features), but in this case, it needs to reign us in and demand clarity in the script.

You only need to improve your syntax.

Use curly brackets to fix it up.  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c742470b681a8cce2d9dc560ed4058ce9b8c17eb))

```
<?php
  class foo {
    public $foo;
    public $bar;

    function __construct() {
      $this->foo = 'Foo';
      $this->bar = array('Bar1', 'Bar2', 'Bar3');
    }
  }

  $foo = new foo();
  $name = 'MyName';

  echo "My name is \"$name\". I am printing some $foo->foo.
  Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.";
?>
```

A similar demo from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (though this one is using nowdoc, not double quotes -- still it is wrapping in `{}`):

[image]

Comment: I know the solution i.e. enclose the expression into curly braces{}. My question is still unanswered. I'm still not understanding the why the way to access both of these entities is different?